# what are the exact possible outputs for bitwise AND operator?

Tags: java, output, bit-manipulation

Question: Given an integer array nums where every element appears three times except for one, which appears exactly once. Find the single element and return it.

i have given the answer below,

```
 int ans=0;
      
       for(int bitPos=0;bitPos<=31;bitPos++)
       {
            int count=0;
           for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
           {
               int check=arr[i]&(1<<bitPos);

           ** if(check!=0)** // if (check==1)
               count++;

           }
           if(count%3==1)
           ans+=1<<bitPos;
       }
       return ans;
```

here when i used " if (check==1)count++ ", i wasn't getting the correct output. but bitwise and will either give 1 or 0 right. so why it's not working ??

details of my approach: every number is repeating thrice except one number

1. I'm trying to count 'ones' in each bit.
2. it will be either in multiple of 3(due to repeating numbers), or multiple of three + 1.(for the non-repeating number).
3. adding all the power of bit positions which has that extra 'one' will give my final answer.

Comment: No, bitwise AND will output 1 or 0 for each and every **bit** of that number so for example `9 & 12` in decimal would be `1001 & 1100` in binary which is `1000` in binary, which is 8 in decimal (neither 1 nor 0).

Comment: It's not clear how you think your solution applies to the problem, which doesn't refer to bits at all.  Possibly you are not clear on the meaning of "Array", "Element" and "bit" ? Try adding an explanation of how your solution works.

Comment: Here’s a hint: try printing out the result of a bitwise and of a value with itself `System.out.println(123 & 123);` as well as a bitwise and of two different values `System.out.println(123 & 456);` Experiment with various same and different values. Do you see a pattern?